# Browser doesn't load .jnlp file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have developed web application. I am browsing url which has .jnlp file. When browse the url it ask me down load the content instead of loading page into browser. Same URL i tried in another person system where it work fine. CAn anybody help me out? What setting should I do to load the page in browser?(I have copied MIME content type in Web.xml file of tomcat server)

Comment: Do you use Apache as a front-end ? Have you configured its MIME type ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, add these lines to your httpd.conf:

```
AddType application/x-java-jnlp-file .jnlp
AddType application/x-java-archive .jar
AddType application/x-java-archive-diff .jardiff
```